# How to dynamically change the properties of a text box in xaml

Tags: silverlight, xaml, styles

I have created a text box using xaml. I have a file named `styles.xaml` which has all the properties of the text box. Now I want to change the properties (height, widht etc.) dynamically through `styles.xaml`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add a resource dictionary reference to your app.xaml

   ```
   <Application.Resource>

      <ResourceDictionary Source="styles.xaml"/> 

   </Application.Resources>
   ```
2. Use this.Resources in your code-behind to access your style resource.

   ```
   Style txtStyle = App.Current.Resources["TextBoxStyle"] as Style;
   ```
3. Set the style on your textbox

   ```
   testTxtBox.Style=txtStyle
   ```

Comment: Thanks, that is a start but I am not able to access the width property in the setter from the code behind. My style file has something like this 
'<Grid.Resources> 

<Style x:Key="lineDataPointStyle" TargetType="chartingToolkit:LineDataPoint">

 <Setter Property="Background" "DarkGreen"/> 
 <Setter Property="Width" Value="200"/> 
 <Setter Property="Height" Value="600"/> 
</Style>'

I want to change the value of width.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.style%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property of the Textbox.

```
myTextbox.Style = Application.Current.Resources["NewTextboxStyle"] as Style;
```